# SLURM: what is the REQUEUED state?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

What is the REQUEUED state in SLURM? I can't find any mention of it in the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html) (search 'state_list').

I'm looking into why some jobs are getting cancelled/requeued on my cluster. The default hypothesis is that it is priority (QOS) preemption. But it seems to be happening way more than it should. I tried looking into it to see whether these jobs got preempted:

```
sacct --allusers --qos=normal --state=PREEMPTED --starttime=2017-06-1 --duplicates --format=jobid,elapsed,qos,user,state,exitcode
```

And there are very few results, and none of the jobs from users who have recently reported lots of preemptions.

When I try searching for the sacct information of the jobs of one of these users, many jobs have been in the REQUEUED state. So it seems preemption *isn't* the issue, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the real issue actually is.

Comment: I have seen jobs requeued when prolog failed. But then nodes are drained. Is it the case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with prolog/epilog, but I don't think this has been associated with nodes draining.